# Migrating jobs from CruiseControl to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cruisecontrol

Could anyone point me to the resources which would help me with the process of migrating my CruiseControl jobs to Jenkins with an easy transition?

My Jenkins is hosted on a Windows Server and 
CruiseControl is hosted on a WebSphere Server